# Point of Infinite Discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

In the image, isn't $1$ also the point of infinite discontinuity? I can't understand why $0$ is the only point of discontinuity. Putting $x = 1$ will result in $0$ in the denominator and thus a discontinuous point.

Comment: Please take the time to enter crucial parts of your questions as text. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: Any instructions on how to write mathematical eq here on SO?

Comment: MathJax is used here. You can find a basic tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will use it from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

When $x=1$ the numerator also has $\ln 1 = 0$ so your fraction is of the $0/0$ type -- use L'Hospital's rule, for example...

Comment: Oh yes. On first differentiation, it worked!